# Regular Expression - Block Spam

Tags: php, regex

Could someone lead me on finding a regular expression that blocks a comma separated list of Spam words I already have?

The regular expression needs to match a string with the spam word list I already have.

Not that it matters, but I am using PHP.

Comment: It matters, there are subtle differences in regexp syntax between variants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
 \b(word1|word2|...)\b
```

The `\b` will match between a word character and a non-word character (so that the expression won't match if the words appear as part of a longer word).

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a regular expression that matches anything containing a spamword from you list by replacing you commas with `|` and adding round brackets and word boundaries.

If your spamlist is `"spam1,spam2,spam3"`, your regular expression would be `"\b(spam1|spam2|spam3)\b"`.

Comment: Be careful with this, as it's easy to accidentally block words such as *chardonnay* if you don't specify matching word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to prevent the user from submitting spam data. Such as:

```
var spam_words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
var regex = new RegExp(spam_words.join("|"));

if(regex.test(form_data_you_wanna_test)){
    // stop submit
}else{
    // submit
}
```

Comment: That is useless. Client side checks can easily be bypassed, always check on server side.